# PL/SQL Append_Values Hint gives error message

Tags: oracle, plsql, ora-06512

I am having trouble doing a large number of inserts into an Oracle table using PL/SQL. My query goes row-by-row and for each row the query makes a calculation to determine the number of rows it needs to insert into the another table. The conventional inserts work but the code takes a long time to run for a large number of rows. To speed up the inserts I tried to use the `Append_Values` hint as in the following example:

```
BEGIN
FOR iter in 1..100 LOOP
INSERT /*+ APPEND_VALUES*/ INTO test_append_value_hint values (iter);
END LOOP;
END;
```

I get the following error message when doing this:

```
ORA-12838: cannot read/modify an object after modifying it in parallel
ORA-06512: at line 3
12838. 00000 -  "cannot read/modify an object after modifying it in parallel"
*Cause:    Within the same transaction, an attempt was made to add read or
           modification statements on a table after it had been modified in parallel
           or with direct load. This is not permitted.
*Action:   Rewrite the transaction, or break it up into two transactions
           one containing the initial modification and the second containing the
           parallel modification operation.
```

Does anyone have ideas of how to make this code work, or how to quickly insert large numbers of rows into another table?

Comment: Where are the rows coming from?  Do you really just want to insert the numbers 1 to 100?  Or are you really pulling the data from some source?

Comment: I am given a table with individuals as well as the start dates and end dates that the individuals enrolled in a program. For the output table, I need a row for each month/year that the individual was enrolled in the program. So if an individual has a start date of 12/21/2012 and an end date of 4/10/2013, I would need five records for the individual (a record for 12/2012, 01/2013, 02/2013, 03/2013, and 04/2013).

My PL/SQL code without the APPEND_VALUES hint works well for small tables, but my table has about one million rows.

Comment: Rather do not use it. Especially from PL/SQL it should be possible to rewrite the code into pure SQL "insert /* +APPEND */ ..select". Moreover this solution does not scale because only one session can append to a table at the same time. Moreover direct path write is used only under some circumstances, like no FKs on a table. If you really want do speedup your ETL use `ALTER SESSION FORCE PARALLEL DML`.

Answer (score 4):

You get this error because every your INSERT executes as a separate DML statement. Oracle prevents read/write on the table where data were added using direct path insert until commit.
Technically you can use PL/SQL collections and FORALL instead:

```
SQL> declare
  2   type array_t is table of number index by pls_integer;
  3   a_t array_t;
  4  begin
  5    for i in 1..100 loop
  6      a_t(i) := i;
  7    end loop;
  8    forall i in 1..100
  9      insert /*+ append_values */ into t values (a_t(i));
 10  end;
 11  /
```

But the question Justin asked is in action - where are your data coming from and why can't you use usual INSERT /*+ append */ INTO ... SELECT FROM approach ?

Answer (score 3):

Hi Request you to use commit after insert as below:

```
BEGIN
FOR iter in 1..100 LOOP
INSERT /*+ APPEND_VALUES*/ INTO test_append_value_hint values (iter);
COMMIT;
END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Yep, +1 - it's not the Append hint that causes the error - it's the fact Oracle balks at modifying a table again after just modifying it.

Answer (score 1):

We cannot execute 2 DML transactions in a table without committing the first transaction. And hence this error will be thrown.

SO, commit your previous transaction in that table and continue the second transaction.